# Point out the SSRS to a new SQL Instance

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have this SSRS report being pointed out to a SQL server instance A and now since we have migrated to a higher version of SQL server. I want to make sure that its pointing out to the new sql instance. can someone tell me how do i do that ? or any documentation on that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is usually stored in a **Data Source**. Your report may either have a Shared Data Source in the project or an embedded Data Source in the report.

If everything else is the same, you just need to check the server name in the Connection String to make sure it's your new server.

[image]

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156450(v=sql.105).aspx